# how to do databend/datamosh?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, abstract

been noticing this datamosh/databend trend picking up everywhere. Anyone know the best ways to accomplish this in photoshop? here's some images of ways i've seen it done:
[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: surprisingly i find it easier to achieve in MS Paint than in PS, at least I don't know a way to scuff selections on PS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that you don't use Photoshop.

You backup your photo or video, and then open a copy in HEX editor and then "find and replace" byte fragments to get different effects (or break the file). You open the result with appropriate software.

VLC is a good choice to open the mangled copy since it is very fault tolerant and can read video, audio and still imagery. If you cannot save the result properly from VLC, you screen-cap it.

Some people take the pixel data stream and feed it through an audio filter, and then put it back into the image container.

It is important to understand that all files are fundamentally the same, they just differ in how they are treated by the software that opens it.

Databending it the intentional corruption and degradation of a file for artistic purposes. This was big in the 80s for analog video art: probably the entire animation department at my Art University did this sort of thing. They might run a video signal through a musical distortion filter etc.